# Create separate worksheets for every row plus headers, transposed

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am super new to VBA and have tried a few variations on what I'm trying to accomplish with no luck so far. I'm on excel for mac 16.37.

I have a workbook that contains columns for about 93 data points representing a status update assessment from a database of clients. Each row represents one status update assessment. Our database vendor does not have a native way to print separate assessments for clients so I am trying to create a macro that will allow me to print all of a client's assessments should they ask for a printed copy.

An example can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PnB4F9W-OsdpTIeg1mfmhT32XMxUCHcA/view?usp=sharing), and this is what I did manually:

- In the example there are two assessments, so I created two tabs and named the tabs the date of the assessment.
- Left justified both columns
- Moved "Project Status Date" to the top row so this can be used as a header and printed at the top of each page
- Adjusted width of columns

If there is a way to copy each row, transposed, one after the other so that everything is in one vertical sheet and the assessments will print one after the other I would also be interested in that.

I know this is pretty vague but I'm hoping it's a simple fix that I'm not seeing because I'm so unfamiliar with VBA. I would appreciate anyone's pointers!

Answer (score 0):

This code may be solve your problem or it may be give you a point :

```
Sub CreateSheetsAndCopyInfos()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Sheets("Source").Select
    r = 2
    Do Until Cells(r, "A").Value = "" ' Or whatever you think better
        Application.StatusBar = "Create Sheet: P" & r
        'Delete Old Sheet If exist
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name = "P" & r Then 'p for person , r is row number
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                sh.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "P" & r

        Sheets("Source").Select
        Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(1, 93)).Select 'Header Row
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("P" & r).Select 'Target
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

        Sheets("Source").Select
        Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, 93)).Select 'person Row
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("P" & r).Select 'Target
        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Done."
End Sub
```